# Sharing oracle transaction between Entity Framework and Oracle Client

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, transactions

I'm working with a legacy application that accesses an oracle database through `System.Data.OracleClient` using an `OracleTransaction` like so:

```
Public Sub ExecuteOracleSql(ByVal sql As String)
        Dim oCmd As New OracleCommand(sql, _dbConnection)
        Try
            oCmd.Transaction = _transaction 'OracleTransaction
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Finally
            oCmd.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

We've since made the decision that all new development will occur via Entity Framework, however we'd like to enlist in the same transaction that is being used by the legacy code.

After some research I discovered the `ObjectContext.Connection.EnlistTransaction()` method, however this accepts a `System.Transaction.Transaction` and not an `OracleTransaction` as above.

Therefore is it possible to share a transaction between the legacy code and EF?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the way to do this is to do this is through accessing the connection from your `ObjectContext` and casting it to an `EntityConnection`.  Doing this allows you to use plain old ADO.NET (which is exactly what I needed).

```
    var lines = new BillLines.BillLines(); //This is the object context

    var conn = ((EntityConnection) lines.Connection).StoreConnection;
    conn.Open();

    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       //Access your data here
    }

    conn.Close();
```